# Remove duplicate sequences from fasta file based on ID

Tags: python, biopython

I wrote a tiny biopython script to extract sequences from a fasta file based on ID but it does extract duplicates so I am looking to filter sequences from my fasta files which are duplicate (e.g. have the exact same ID).

I tried to modify my script but I failed:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

id = []
for line in open("short.txt","r"):
    id.append(line.rstrip().strip('"'))


for rec in SeqIO.parse("out.fa","fasta"):
    #print rec.id
    if rec.id in id:
        if rec.id not in rec.format:
            print rec.format("fasta")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids = set()
for rec in blah:
    if rec.id not in ids:
        ids.add(rec.id)
        # process it
```

Comment: It does not seem to work

Comment: @user3188922: Generally when people post "it doesn't work," no further useful help will be given, because there's not a good way for us to understand what your problem is.  If you want help, you need to be explicit about *what* does not work, what errors you see if any, what your input and output data look like, etc.  Not "here is some random code, it doesn't work."

Comment: Sorry it actually works perfectly :) my bet! I thought idS was a mistake and should be id instead but otherwise opening a new set of ids is a great idea!